# Are "other" flags containing "spam" prioritized like actual spam flags?

Tags: support, flags, spam

Sometimes I come across non-obvious spam, or posts that *might* be spam but I'm not sure. I cast custom "other" flags with text like "Possible spam attempt: new user posted half-promotional answer with a link to a domain parking page."  On its own that post might just be misguided, but if there's more than one account making those kinds of posts it would certainly be spam.  I don't have enough information to decide, so I want a mod to look at it.  (I'm also aware that the penalties from successful spam flags will cause them to be declined more often than a custom flag describing a reasonable suspicion that turns out to not be an issue, which is an incentive to use "other" flags.)

Apparently the mods have a separate queue for spam flags.  Are "other" flags containing the word "spam" similarly prioritized?  Should I just use normal spam flags instead and trust the mod handling it to investigate thoroughly?  Use *both* kinds of flag?

Comment: If the mod thinks it's spam, then they will do a spam flag on it, even though you flagged as other. I use the other flag when a user has multiple answers (*all technically related to the question)* , but all of them are promoting the same site/product/etc and let the moderator handle it how they see fit. If it's obvious spam I'll flag as spam.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, "other" flags containing the word "spam" are not displayed to us in the spam flag grouping. Unfortunately, due to the current grouping of things in the moderator tools, these flags go into the middle of all our other custom flags, which can sometimes be difficult to prioritize.

I do try to search through the most recent custom flags to find higher-priority flags like this, but sometimes they slip through and get buried amid the piles of other flags that we really don't need to act on immediately.

If we do find that it is spam, we can apply a binding spam flag to it and feed the post into the anti-spam system. We can also search for similar users who might be spamming the same thing, and destroy the account. How we act on a flag once we see a spammer isn't affected by the type of flag originally cast.

I personally prefer to get more detailed flags with custom descriptions, so that we can better understand what you saw. These just sometimes can be handled a little more slowly than standard spam / offensive flags. I'm hopeful that this process can be improved in the near term with some of the proposed changes being worked on.