# Spam flag declined - not sure why

Tags: discussion, spam

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29054549/1864610) was asked today. It appears to be a rather questionable rant about some issue with Safari that the OP wants to take legal action over. The question is definitely off-topic, but the link is what caused me to raise the spam flag. The site it leads to has nothing to do with the OP's claim, but seems to be doing nothing more than soliciting BitCoins. The question is undoubtedly spam, but my flag was declined on the grounds that there's 'no evidence to support it'. The same mod who declined my flag also went ahead and deleted the question.

Can someone explain what the reasoning was here, please?

For the benefit of the 10k- users, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: **He wants to sue because he can't HTML?!** *Crazies... Crazies everywhere.* Web-design is the science of crafting markup that works in all browsers not suing browsers because they can't handle your pseudo-markup. #LOL

Comment: Can we get a close reason on meta for questions like these?  It seems like a _lot_ of questions are effectively "A mod declined my flag and then later deleted the post anyway", and the reason is _always_ "At first glance it didn't look like a problem, but after more flags I looked more carefully", which is perfectly normal and happens all the time (and is, basically, what should happen, given scarce mod resources).

Comment: @joe something like "Closed - resolved" would work well, no?

Comment: I mean more like with an explanation baked into the close reason, so the mod doesn't have to explain in nitty gritty detail every single time.  (A close as duplicate might work okay as well, to another similar question or a canonical version of this.)

Comment: Nice one going the extra mile to sniff out the spam.

Comment: Based on the user name and the site domain, isn't this the site that he's complaining about Safari messing up? So "The site it leads to has nothing to do with the OP's claim" is false. Sounds like a terrible question, not spam per se.

Comment: In support of ChrisF's musing below: [*Add optional box for spam flags letting you say why you think it's spam*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288127/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-when-you-think-its-spam) - if we'd had that, you could have said why you flagged it that way (e.g., you went and looked).

Comment: @joe: doesn't that make them duplicates?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

That would have been me.

Yours was the first flag and at first glance it did appear to be a valid, if really low quality, question. As such I thought that it was worthy of down-votes and votes to close but not immediate deletion.

We get people who link to their legitimate site when asking questions and there are some users who flag them as spam regardless, so I am always prepared to give the questioner the benefit of the doubt.

However, the question then gained two more spam flags in quick succession so I took another look and conceded that I'd made a mistake the first time in not just deleting the post.

It's a shame that there's not an optional text box on spam/offensive flags where you could have explained what you explained here, as had I had more information available I probably wouldn't have declined your flag.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,Chris. I guess we're all human!

Comment: Chris is clearly a dog.

Comment: [Remember when, on the Internet, nobody knew who you were?](http://newyorker.tumblr.com/post/111446912131/a-cartoon-by-kaamran-hafeez-from-this-weeks)

Comment: [On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog)

Comment: *"It's a shame that there's not an optional text box on spam/offensive flags where you could have explained"* -> In cases where a little extra explanation might be useful, but a "needs ♦ moderator attention"-flag isn't appropriate, I just leave a comment on the post. In this case, something like: "Flagged as spam: the link has nothing to do with the asked question, and just seems to be about selling bitboins".

Comment: I leave "other" flags, but [I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288045/are-other-flags-containing-spam-prioritized-like-actual-spam-flags).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - spam should be flagged with the spam flag. I was just musing that it *might* be useful to have more information on some occasions.

Comment: @ChrisF: Your musing seems quite useful, and thus: [*Add optional box for spam flags letting you say why you think it's spam*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288127/add-optional-box-for-spam-flags-letting-you-say-when-you-think-its-spam)

Comment: Bitboins. Love it. *goes off to create yet another cryptocurrency*

Comment: This seems to be a common problem, hence I have just created a feature request, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288201/when-a-flag-is-declined-then-the-post-is-deleted-closed-later-auto-review-the